# Canned Moderation Responses

Tags: discussion, moderation, comments, community-wiki

I have a doc that I keep with some "canned" moderation responses. I add them as comments when going through the mod queue. Since a large portion of the community participates in moderation activities, I thought I would share them in case others would find them useful.

My goal with these is to offer polite, constructive criticism for users who appear not to understand how our site works. None of these are appropriate for users who are rude, abusive, engaged in excessive self-promotion, spammers, etc.

I won't pretend these are perfect. In fact, I'm certain that they're not. I would love to see the community evolve and improve these. If you do, I'd be more than happy to use the new version.

If you have your own, please share them as well.

Comment: I realize that this isn't quite in the "spirit" of Q&A, but I use these things so often that I wanted to share them. If you don't believe that this belongs on meta, downvote it. If there's reasonably strong objection, I'll delete it.

Comment: This is pretty cool. I wonder if there's a way to create templates of these, in the style of Wikipedia warnings.

Answer (score 12):

**Comment as an answer**

`Welcome to Bicycles SE. This site does not operate like a typical forum. It operates on a Q&A basis. Please only use the "answer" button to answer the OP's question. Once you have asked and answered a few questions, you'll have earned enough [reputation](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) to [comment everywhere](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) on the site.`

---

**Not an answer**

`Welcome to Bicycles SE. This site does not operate like a typical forum. It operates on a Q&A basis. This post does not attempt to answer the OP’s question. Please only use the "answer" button to answer the OP's question. Please see our [help pages](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help) or take our [tour] for more information about how the site works.`

---

**New Question as answer**

`Welcome to Bicycles SE. This site does not operate like a typical forum. It operates on a Q&A basis. Please use the "Answer" button only to answer the OP's question. If you feel these answers don't address your issue, please ask a [new question](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can find out more about how our site works by taking our [tour].`

---

**“Me Too” answer**

`Welcome to Bicycles SE. This site does not operate like a typical forum. It operates on a Q&A basis. Please use the "Answer" button only to answer the OP's question. If you feel these answers don't address the issue, you can [add a bounty](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).You can find out more about how our site works by taking our [tour].`

---

**Thank you as an answer**

`Welcome to Bicycles SE. This site does not operate like a typical forum. It operates on a Q&A basis. Please only use the "answer" button to answer the OP's question. Once you have asked and answered a few questions, you'll have earned enough [reputation](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) to [vote up questions and answers](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful.`

---

**Use proper English**

`Welcome to Bicycles SE. We ask that you [write to the best of your ability](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on this site. This means proper capitalization, proper punctuation, and complete sentences. I have made some edits for you. If you feel I have inadvertently changed the nature of your question, feel free to correct me.`

---

**More Detail**

`Welcome to Bicycles SE. We're looking for answers with [more detail](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Please consider editing your answer to explain _____fill_in_here________. A short, one-line answer like this is likely to get downvoted, flagged for moderator intervention, and possibly deleted.`

---

**Open-ended question/forum type discussion**

`Welcome to Bicycles SE. This site is not a typical forum. Like all Stack Exchange sites, we operate on a Q&A format. We are looking for questions with specific answers [rather than open-ended discussions](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Once you have asked and answered a few questions, you'll have earned enough [reputation](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) to participate in our [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/214/the-velodrome), where this kind of discussion would be welcome.`

---

**Link only answer**

`Welcome to Bicycles SE. [We prefer answers on this site to be self-contained](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). That way, the answer is still valid if the link dies. Please use the [edit] button to summarize the information is contained in the linked content within the body of your answer. Otherwise, it is likely to be downvoted, flagged for moderator intervention, and possibly deleted.`

---

**Unclear Answer**

`Welcome to Bicycles Stack Exchange! Unfortunately, your answer is very hard to understand. I suggest reading [How do I write a good answer](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) in the [Help Center](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help) for information on how to compose a good answer. You can edit your answer to make it easier to understand with the "edit" button at the bottom of the answer. If you do not do so, it is likely to be downvoted, flagged for moderator intervention, and possibly deleted.`

---

**Unclear Question**

`Welcome to Bicycles Stack Exchange! Unfortunately, your question is very hard to understand. I suggest reading [How do I ask a good question?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) in the [Help Center](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help) for information on how to compose a good question. You can edit your question to make it easier to understand with the "edit" button at the bottom of the question. If you do not do so, it is likely to be downvoted, flagged for moderator intervention, and possibly deleted.`

---

**Comments Extended Discussion/Debate**

`Per the [help center](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment): Comments should not be used for “...secondary discussion or debating a controversial point; please use [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) instead.”`

---

**Edit as Answer**

`Welcome to Bicycles SE. Please use the “Answer” button only to answer questions. If you would like to add further information to your initial post, you can use the “Edit” button just underneath your post.`

---

**Self-Promotion**

`Welcome to Bicycles SE. Are you affiliated with the site you mention? If you are, you **must** disclose that affiliation within your answer. http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/behavior`

---

**Be Nice**

`Welcome to Bicycles SE. We ask that you [be nice](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) on this site.`

---

**Edited Product Rec**

`Welcome to Bicycles SE. Product recommendations are [off topic](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for this site. As such, I have removed that portion of your question so that it will not be closed by the community.`

---

**"Identify my bike" Closed Without Pictures**

`Welcome to Bicycles SE. It is nearly impossible to identify a bicycle without pictures. Please [edit] some into your question. Once you do so, the question will automatically be flagged for reopening. You can find out more about how our site works by taking our [tour].`

Comment: I went back and forth in my head on how to format these. The preformatted text is harder to read, but easier to copy/paste. If the community would rather have the easier to read version, that's fine by me.

Comment: I don't have enough rep. yet (on bicycles.se) to review, but based on other sites don't some of these comments (like "comment as answer") largely duplicate the comments left by review?

Comment: @DavidW To encourage community moderation, I've deliberately steered clear of the review queues since being elected a mod, so I don't recall what was in those queues. If you think there are dupes here that are unhelpful, feel free to edit them out once you have the rep. Or, if other users see dupes, feel free to edit them out.

Comment: I don't use it, and I've lost the link, but someone told me about a plug-in they use that allows them to do a quick-select-auto-fill of the comments box from a set of canned responses.  Combining that with these standard responses would make review very efficient.  (Probably be complete overkill for the amount traffic for this site, but makes sense on SO.)

Comment: Love these, I used them in the review queue just now. I've added in the square brackets around edit where it is directly in a sentence to give [edit].

Comment: Another one    [ t o u r ] gives [tour] and doesn't need the URL after it, is a special keyword like [ e d i t ] which resolves to [edit]

Comment: Turns out there's a lot more Magic Links documented at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments/94000#94000

Answer (score 5):

Links I'm frequently searching for to reference in a comment:

[What is the maximum or minimum tire width I can fit on my bicycle?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52587/)

[How can I tell what year my bike was made?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/47078/)

[Why shouldn't I care what model/make/year my bicycle is?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52060/)

[Terminology Index](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/)

[What is the purpose of a serial number?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/32872/)

[How do I ask a good ID-my-bike question?](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1337/) Meta

https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy 
which is also Bicycles.SE policy, in [What can be done to thwart posting of answers using Chat GPT or other AI Answer Machines?](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1501/what-can-be-done-to-thwart-posting-of-answers-using-chat-gpt-or-other-ai-answer)

---

These should be linked under
[Canonical Answers tag](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/canonical-answer) also.

Request to merge two SE accounts: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/contact?topic=4