# Proposed ChatGPT Ban

Tags: discussion

I propose that we officially ban ChatGPT and other computer-generated questions and answers with the following text on our help page:

#### AI-assisted Generated Content Ban

Please be aware that all AI-assisted generated content (including ChatGPT) is currently banned. This community has chosen to adopt the policy from Stack Overflow. For more information, see:

- [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently acceptable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy)
- [Temporary policy: ChatGPT is banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831)

Comment: Vote for the one you like. Feel free to comment or post a new question with a different proposed ban.

Comment: 8 upvotes on the question, 10 upvotes on the "yes" answer, 0 upvotes on the "no" answer. Seems pretty definitive. Posting the policy.

Comment: [Relevant to this discussion](https://openletter.mousetail.nl/)

Comment: @AdamRice Thanks for raising this. The mods are aware of the ongoing network-level discussions about AI generated content, though I had not personally seen this open letter.

Answer (score 24):

Yes, I support adopting the ban.

Comment: I reiterate my [previous argument](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1502/43557) in favour of this policy.

Comment: @DavidW Yeah, I kind of figured there was general support for a ban. But based on a comment on [another answer](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1504/4239) to that same meta question, I wanted to get confirmation as well as some specific language for the community to vote on.

Comment: That's fair; this question is clear and unambiguous, and makes a good target for "this has already been decided [link]" comments.  I just didn't feel like condensing my argument down to the size of a comment, but still felt it was relevant. :)

Answer (score 0):

No, I do not support adopting the ban.